# Faker Python generating chinese/pinyin names

Tags: python, cjk, faker

I am trying to generate random chinese names using Faker (Python), but it generates the names in chinese characters instead of pinyin.

I found this :
[image]

and it show that it generates them in pinyin, while when I try the same code, it gives me only chinese characters.

how to get the pinyin ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fake.romanized_name()` worked for me.

I got lucky by looking through `dir(fake)`. Doesn't seem to have a method for pinyin address that I can see...